# Сгруппировать результат по дням, посчитав для каждого дня кол-во элементов таблицы

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!

У меня имеется таблица, назовем ее условно "auth". Ее структуру упрощу до такого вида, чтобы было понятнее:

```
id          INT(11) PK AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id     INT(11)
date        DATETIME
```

Допустим, в нее записываются авторизации пользователей (user_id) в некую систему, и дата авторизации (date). Один пользователь может иметь множество авторизаций, отношение один ко многим.

Моей задачей является средствами MySQL вывести отчет по выбранному временному промежутку (от и до) следующего вида:

```
user    |   2015-01-01  |   2015-01-02  |   2015-01-03  |
        |               |               |               |
x       |   2           |   0           |   3           |
y       |   0           |   1           |   1           |
z       |   0           |   0           |   1           |
```

В этом примере запрошено кол-во авторизаций пользователей x, y и z (user_id IN (x, y, z)), за промежуток от 2015-01-01 до 2015-01-03 (date >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND date <= '2015-01-03 23:59:59')

Как я могу вывести многомерный по сути результат и расположить даты отчета "по горизонтали", причем подставив недостающие даты (или хотя бы без них)?

Вот так я могу вывести количество авторизаций, но только для одного пользователя (x):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS CNT, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') as DATE 
FROM 
    auth 
WHERE 
    user_id = x
GROUP BY 
    DATE 
ORDER BY
    DATE DESC;
```

Но как сделать это для нескольких пользователей, как в примере? Неужели для каждого пользователя придется сделать вложенный селект на количество авторизаций по датам?

Спасибо!

Comment: *Но как сделать это для нескольких пользователей* — очевидно, надо убрать ограничение на `user_id`. менее очевидно — надо добавить `user_id` в список группировки. примерно: `select ... from auth group by user_id, date order by ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но как сделать это для нескольких пользователей

очевидно, надо убрать ограничение на `user_id`. менее очевидно — надо добавить `user_id` в список группировки. см. первый запрос ниже.

> Как я могу вывести многомерный по сути результат и расположить даты отчета "по горизонтали", причем подставив недостающие даты (или хотя бы без них)?

например, так, как во втором запросе ниже. формировать столбцы динамически лучше не срествами *sql* (это довольно неэффективно и весьма громоздко), а средствами вышестоящего, более подходящего для этого языка.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25016/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table auth (u int, d datetime);

insert into auth values
   (1, "2015-11-04 17:00")
  ,(1, "2015-11-05 18:00")
  ,(1, "2015-11-05 19:00")
  ,(2, "2015-11-04 20:00")
  ,(2, "2015-11-04 21:00")
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select u
  ,count(*) as cnt
  ,date(d) as date
from auth
group by u, date
order by date desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25016/3/0)**:

```
| u | cnt |                       date |
|---|-----|----------------------------|
| 1 |   2 | November, 05 2015 00:00:00 |
| 1 |   1 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
| 2 |   2 | November, 04 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select u
  ,sum(date(d) = "2015-11-04") as `2015-11-04`
  ,sum(date(d) = "2015-11-05") as `2015-11-05`
from auth
group by u
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25016/3/1)**:

```
| u | 2015-11-04 | 2015-11-05 |
|---|------------|------------|
| 1 |          1 |          2 |
| 2 |          2 |          0 |
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. без парсинга в нужный вид результата запроса вышестоящим языком не обошлось все же.